# Update querystring on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are n input boxces, if user checked any check boxce, value in query string should be add in with name of check box and if user uncheck the check box, value should be omit.If there is same name of check boxes ,value should should add with comma separated.
Ex. ?name1=1,2,3&name2=9,8,10

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve   what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("template_filters").on("change", "input", function(event, element) {
    var path        =   window.location.search.substring(1);
    var attr_name   =   element.name;
    var attr_val    =   element.readAttribute('data-id');
    var currentqueryVar =   path.toQueryParams();
    var org_path    =   window.location.href;
    var cleanUrl    =   org_path.split('?');
    if(path.length > 0 && typeof currentqueryVar[attr_name] !== 'undefined')
    {   
        var paramArray = path.split("&");
        var n = new Array();
        var i;
        for (i=0;i<paramArray.length;i++)
        {
           var  currentParameter = paramArray[i].split("=");
           if(currentParameter[0]==attr_name)//Parameter already exists in current url
           {
                var old_q_val   =   currentParameter[1].split(',');
                if(old_q_val.indexOf(attr_val)=== -1)
                    old_q_val.push(attr_val);
                else
                {
                    var unset_index = old_q_val.indexOf(attr_val);
                    if(unset_index != -1){
                         old_q_val.splice(unset_index, 1);
                    } 
                }
                currentParameter[1] =old_q_val.join();
           }
           if(currentParameter[1]!='')
                n.push(currentParameter[0]+'='+currentParameter[1]);
        }
        var queryStrnig ='?'+ n.join("&");
    }
    else{
        queryStrnig ='?'+attr_name+'='+ attr_val;
        if(path!='')
            queryStrnig ='?'+path+'&'+attr_name+'='+ attr_val; 
    }
    history.pushState(null, null, cleanUrl[0]+queryStrnig);
    return false;
});
```